# How to update the Chart view when button is touched

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have a Chart that shows the Euro price for each candle and m3 candles, so I want to change it when the user touch the button for example if its in EURO to change it to m3

Library used: danielgindi/Charts

so at chartImage below:

1. the user clicks the button
2. the data needs to change from EURO to m3 and
3. the label needs to change from EURO to m3.

[image]

The code implemented so far:

```
extension dashboardViewController: AxisValueFormatter {
   AxisValueFormatter {

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    print(Int(value))
    return months[Int(value)]
    }
}

@IBAction func euroANDm3(_ sender: Any) {
    euroANDm3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeValue), for: .touchUpInside)
}


@objc func changeValue() {
    uniteuro = uniteurotest
    barChart.reloadInputViews()
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    axisFormatDelegate = self
    
    months = ["Jan",
              "Feb",
              "Mar",
              "Apr",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "Aug",
              "Sep",
              "Oct",
              "Nov",
              "Dec"
    ]
    uniteuro = [43,34,52,39,36,33,55,39,51,45,38,44]
    uniteurotest = [41,41,41,41,41,41,41,39,51,45,38,44]
    
    setChart(dataPoints: months, values: uniteuro)
}


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    barChart.noDataText = "NO DATA"
    
    var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints)
        
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "EUR")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    
    barChart.data = chartData
    
    barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
}
```

Comment: You should tell your readers which charting library you are using.

Comment: (Edit your question to add that info. Don't post it as a comment. Readers should be able to see everything the need to understand your question in the question itself.)

Comment: @DuncanC Done mate.